# Mutating struct property types in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, api, struct, codable

I call an api and depending on the parameters I pass on the call it either returns a **[Standings]** or a **[[Standings]]**. However this is done dynamically depending on the user preferences and tableView didSelectRow. The endpoint is the same for all calls within the specific "click" and the rest of the struct remains the same. Is there a way to decode this one in run time?

```
 struct League: Codable {
    let standings: [Standing]?
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create 2 struct :

```
struct League: Codable {
    let standings: [Standing]?
     ...
}

struct StandingsLeague: Codable {
    let standings: [[Standing]]?
    ...
}
```

And depending on "depending on the parameters I pass on the call" parse the structure you need. Or you can through do-catch:

```
do {
   let parserResult = try decoder.decode(League.self, from: data)
} catch {
  do {
     let parserResult = try decoder.decode(StandingsLeague.self, from: data)
  catch {
  }
}
```